# What this array defined as static and not global?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm just started to learn C language from [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_return_arrays_from_function.htm).

In the part that I linked above, author want to return an array from a function and he wrote :

> C does not advocate to return the address of a local variable to
>   outside of the function so you would have to define the local variable
>   as static variable.

I understand the reason of preventing to return address of a local variable. The reason is that the local variable is not available outside of its scope, and so having its address outside of the function can make bugs in runtime.

But the parts that I don't understand is that Why we must define the array **Static** and not **Global**?

Defining a local array as static will change its lifetime only or it will change its scope also?

This is the program that I talk about:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* function to generate and return random numbers */
int * getRandom( )
{
  static int  r[10];
  int i;

  /* set the seed */
  srand( (unsigned)time( NULL ) );
  for ( i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
  {
     r[i] = rand();
     printf( "r[%d] = %d\n", i, r[i]);

  }

  return r;
}

/* main function to call above defined function */
int main ()
{
   /* a pointer to an int */
   int *p;
   int i;

   p = getRandom();
   for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
   {
       printf( "*(p + %d) : %d\n", i, *(p + i));
   }

   return 0;
}
```

**Update:**

This is output of above program:

```
r[0] = 313959809
r[1] = 1759055877
r[2] = 1113101911
r[3] = 2133832223
r[4] = 2073354073
r[5] = 167288147
r[6] = 1827471542
r[7] = 834791014
r[8] = 1901409888
r[9] = 1990469526
*(p + 0) : 313959809
*(p + 1) : 1759055877
*(p + 2) : 1113101911
*(p + 3) : 2133832223
*(p + 4) : 2073354073
*(p + 5) : 167288147
*(p + 6) : 1827471542
*(p + 7) : 834791014
*(p + 8) : 1901409888
*(p + 9) : 1990469526
```

As you see above, the array is accessible outside the `getRandom()` function.How is this possible? It is a local variable!

Comment: Yes, it will change its lifetime.

Comment: The array can only be accessed from `getRandom` after its declaration while for globals, it can be accessed from anywhere. Lifetime of a static and a global variable are the same.

Comment: @CoolGuy The array can only be access from `getRandom`, but its values are available `main()` also. Am I right?

Comment: You can't access it from `main()`. You can return a value or grab a value from the array from `getRandom` and use it in `main()`, though.

Comment: @CoolGuy Please check question update section. (Temporary comment.)

Comment: You probably shouldn't call `srand()` inside the `getRandom()` function. Basically, `srand()` was designed to be called once per program run (not once per function invocation).

Comment: @pmg What's the problem with calling it more than one time?

Comment: @Abraham "_the array is accessible outside the `getRandom()` function.How is this possible? It is a local variable!_" -- You return `r`(address of the first element of the static array) from `getRandom` and use pointer `p` from `main()` to point to this address. This is perfectly valid.

Comment: @Abraham "_What's the problem with calling it more than one time?_" -- Try calling `getRandom` once again. You'll probably get the same "random" values.

Comment: @CoolGuy Certainly not the same values since it's seeded with the time. But depending on what `srand()` does, the first value of each run  may be more similar than without seeding again (because the seeds are fairly close).

Comment: @PeterSchneider CoolGuy is right. I received exactly the same values and I think it is because of the speed of program. I mean I think `time` doesn't change between two calls.It is **almost** the same in first call.

Comment: @CoolGuy Ah, I see. Yes, if you run it within the same second, you get the same seed, true. That could be millions of identical sequences :-)

Comment: Please, change your C learning source... In the first paragraph of your cite it says *"returning a complete array is not allowed as a parameter"*.  What might we thing, **is it a returned thing or is it something passed in as a parameter?**  parameters are different as returned values, do this guy must not mix them.  What is true is that an array cannot be returned from a function, but a pointer to something (even a pointer to an array) can.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The distinct technical concepts and terms are

1. "Scope of an identifier" (i.e. where is *the declared name* visible so that it can be used) vs.
2. "Storage duration of an object", i.e. how long can I legally access the *memory* which constitutes the object -- by any means available, pointers, indexing, an attached identifier or whatever. Another word for that is "object lifetime".

So by saying `int *p = getRandom();` you are introducing an *identifier p with block scope* (because it's inside main) identifying a pointer object with *automatic storage duration* (because it was declared without any storage or linkage qualifications like "extern" or "static"). For `p`, object life time and identifier scope are the same: The block `p` is declared and defined in.

The *value* stored in this local pointer object is the address of an element in the array `r` with *static storage duration*. `r` is declared and defined in `getRandom()`. The *scope of the identifier `r`* is the block of the body of `getRandom()` in which it is declared; you cannot use this **name** `r` anywhere else. But the array **object** itself has *static storage duration* due to the "storage class specifier" *static*. This means that the *lifetime of the array object* is the lifetime of the program. (Yes, it exists even before `getRandom()` has run but I don't think there is a way to legally access it.) That's why you can leak its address anywhere and use it, even if `getRandom()` has long since returned.

Edit: For completeness: Why would anybody do that and not just declare a global identifier for the array? Well, it's an early form of encapsulation (later implementations of `getRandom()` could be different), and it's a way to implement singletons.

And how did I know? I read the [freely available C standard draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). It was, as always, not so easy to find the relevant information, but a simple keyword search helped. Relevant are 6.2.1 for the scope of identifiers and 6.2.4 for the storage duration of objects. Of course the standard is dry and formal but it introduces the proper terminology and, after some accomodation, is quite intelligible.

Answer (score 2):

"Defining a local array as static will change its lifetime only or it will change its scope also?"

- The scope never change.
- But lifetime changes: making a local variable *static* makes it lasts as long as the program does.

Comment: If the scope doesn't change, so why I must extend its lifetime? It is not available in the `main()` anyway! Its available in `getRandom` only.

Comment: @Abraham Alternatively you can make `getRandom` take an array pointer argument and change it to work on that array instead of the static one. This way you would create your array in your `main` method and just pass it to `getRandom` to work with.

Answer (score 0):

A static local variable exists for the duration of the program, but is only visible in the function body. 
Static variables continue to exist even after the block in which they are defined terminates. 
Thus, the value of a static variable in a function is retained between repeated function calls to the same function.

```
So, It will change the lifetime , but leaves scope as it is i.e local to the function
```

Comment: that is possible because you are returning the base address of the array .

Comment: "Static automatic variables" seems a good way to explain the meaning of "oxymoron".

Answer (score 0):

The main differences between a local variable and a static variable are

1) A static variable lasts during the program does

2)The static variables are stored in the BSS segment,however local variables are stored in the stack segment